# What is wrong with my Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="TestHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:updateApplet();" %>' Text="Send" />
```

It says "The server tag is not well formatted."

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing **ID**  Before **"TestHyperLink"**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="TestHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:updateApplet();" %>' Text="Send" />
```

Comment: Hi @MehmetBudak Try onclick="updateApplet();" and Navigateurl="#"

Comment: @ Vinod just send me your picture. I wanna hang it on my wall!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many wrong things, have you ever, at least, bother to look in Google ?

```
<asp:HyperLink 
    id="TestHyperLink" 
    runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="#"
    OnClientClick="updateApplet()"
    Text="Send" />
```

but for simple things like this, you don't need an ASP.NET Control, unless you are doing something from your code file... a simple `<a>` will do the trick.

Just understand that ASP.NET Controls are useful when we want to tweak or use then in our application as variables so we can control them dynamically. If we simply need a link that will never change, there is no need for a control, a html tag will do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't seem to be working.
`<input type="button" value="Update applet" onclick="updateApplet()" />`
With simple html tag, it works, but when it comes to asp, ...